# Can you set the root storage path for the Compute and Storage emulators?

Tags: azure, azure-storage-emulator

Does anybody know how to specify the root path for the Compute and Storage emulators?

Here's my problem: my laptop has a 256GB SSD (C:) as bootdisk and a secondary 1TD HDD for data (D:). By default the emulator is storing it's data in my AppData folder, which is on the C: drive. This eats up precious space on my boot drive so I would like to move it's root path to somewhere on the D: drive.

Anybody have any idea if this is hard wired into the emulator or if there is a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

try the config files in your AppData folder

e.g.,

C:\Users\UserX\AppData\Local\WAStorageEmulator\WAStorageEmulator.3.0.config
or
C:\Users\UserX\AppData\Local\DevelopmentStorage\DevelopmentStorage.201210.config

underneath, the emulator also uses LocalDB, you can connect to LocalDB and try to relocate the databases

also, try setting the _CSRUN_STATE_DIRECTORY environment variable to a different path (either via SET command or via System Properties->Environment Variables->System Variables)

Comment: Modifying WAStorageEmulator.3.0.config solved part of the problem, but the Compute emulator is still running in the AppData folder and my local dev storage account is still there as well in the dftmp\wadd folder.

Only solution to move that I found so far is to create a junction link:

http://superuser.com/questions/447153/can-i-move-the-azure-storage-emulator-files

Comment: see updated answer if it works, you need to reboot if you set the system variable